# How Can I know where is an user from in determinated day hour? (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Hi I have an user that use my webpage from Ukraine (I'm from other country), and I want to know what time he entered in my website.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All data is aggregated so unless that user is the only person from Ukraine, you cannot tell which user it would be. It is actually easier if you go through the API route if you need to do it from time to time. It requires some initial set up but it is quite straightforward after.

1. Configure your API credential
2. Pull a report by country and hour.
3. Look for the hour with a single session.
4. Add any dimension that can help you narrow down the session as needed.

The following example is done in R, but the concept is the same for any other languages.

```
install.packages('RGoogleAnalytics')
library(RGoogleAnalytics)

token <- Auth(client.id = "yourownclientid",
             client.secret = "yourownclientsecret")

GetProfiles(token)
query.list <- Init(start.date = "2018-11-08",
               end.date = "2018-11-08",
               dimensions = "ga:dateHour,ga:country",
               filters = "ga:country%3D%3DUkraine",
               metrics = "ga:sessions",
               max.results = 1000,
               table.id = "ga:yourownviewidfromtheprofilelistabove")
ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)
ga.df <- GetReportData(ga.query, token)
ga.df
```

Then, you can see the result like this one:

```
 dateHour country sessions
1  2018110804  Ukraine       1
```

Then you know the single session from Ukraine happens in the 4th hour of the day.
The help file is pretty concise but it should provide sufficient info for you as well.